# Triggering a mouse hover event on a toolbar item

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp, swtbot

I have an RCP app for which I am using SWTBot to implement UI tests.
I have a particular use case that I can't seem to be able to generate tests for.

I have a view that contains several items in its toolbar. One of them reacts to a mouse hover event only and I haven't found a way yet to trigger a mouse hover event in SWTBot for this particular toolbar item.

Any ideas how to do that ?
Here is my attempt so far that results in the below exception:

```
final IToolBarManager items = mySwtBotView.getViewReference().getView(false).getViewSite().getActionBars().getToolBarManager();
      for (final IContributionItem item : items.getItems()) {

            final Widget widget = (Widget) item;
            widget.notifyListeners(SWT.MouseHover, null);
      }

java.lang.ClassCastException: class MyToolbarAction cannot be cast to class org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget (class MyToolbarAction is in unnamed module of loader org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader @68aa43bb;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: To get the widgets you need the ToolBar not the ToolBarManager. The `IToolBarManager` may be `org.eclipse.jface.action.ToolBarManager` which has a `getControl` method to access the tool bar.

Comment: I tried to use the `getControl` but I get this error now:
    `items.getControl().notifyListeners(SWT.MouseHover, null);
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid thread access`

Comment: You can only do things like that on the main SWT UI thread. I don't know if SWTBot supports that.

Comment: [it doesn't seem so](https://wiki.eclipse.org/SWTBot/FAQ#Why_do_tests_run_on_a_non-UI_thread.3F), no